# Dialogflow: Not able to identify simple phrases

Tags: dialogflow-es

Not able to identify simple phrases like "my name is not Harry, it's Sam".

It is giving me name as harry and company name as Sam, Since name and company name was required in the same sentence.

It should have taken name as Sam and prompted the user again for company name OR should have given complete fallback.

Comment: Have you specify the custom names in entities.

Comment: Can you update your question to show screen shots of the Intent you think should handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow.

Dude. This is not a simple phrase.
Negative questions are always very difficult to catch by Dialogflow.

Suppose I have a question like,

`I want to check *google* revenue for the year *2017*`

As you can see, google and 2017 are the entities.
But now in the same way if you say,

`I don't want to check *google* revenue for the year *2017*`

The chances of hitting that old intent is very high as dialogflow matches almost 90% of this sentence with your old sentence. So it might fail.

Hope you are trying to ask something similar to this.

Anyhow coming to your point, If `company name` and `name` are different entities, then

Two things you can avoid:

1. As everyone mentioned,check your entities. The values should not be present in both the entities. This will fail because dialogflow will not know whether it should treat 'Sam' as your name or company name.
2. If you are not using the values from an entity, instead using '$ANY', then It has a very high chance of failing. And If you are using Dialogflow's system entity like, $given-name, then that is also not preferred as it does not catch all the names. So avoid these entities.

Things you can try:

1. Train Train And Train. As you would be aware, the training section in dialogflow is pretty good. Train it a few times and it will automatically learn and master it.
   But , please note: Wrong training will result in wrong results. It should be 100% accurate. Always check before you approve a training.
2. And try using webHooks, actions, and/or events to figuring your way out from an external API.